# jquery AJAX JSON transform to multiple table

Tags: json, ajax

I have a little problem with this code:

```js
var tab_etat_initial_joueur=[];
for(var i=0; i<20; i++)
   tab_etat_initial_joueur[i] = [];
console.log("grille:"+tab_etat_initial_joueur);
/************************************************************************************************************/
// chargement de la page
//    chargement des donnees
/************************************************************************************************************/
  $(function(){
       $.ajax({
         url   :"./code/grille_presence/liste_etats_joueurs.php", 
         type  :"POST",
         cache  :false,
         dataType :"json",
         error  : function(request,error){
            alert("Erreur : responseText: "+request.responseText);
            },
         success  : function(reponse)
            {
             console.log(reponse);
             $.each(reponse,function(i,item){
             var tab_temp = [];
             var etat_temp = item.id_etat_joueur_initial;
             var date_temp = item.id_date;
             var joueur_temp = item.id_joueur;
             tab_temp[joueur_temp]=etat_temp;
             tab_etat_initial_joueur[date_temp]=tab_temp;
             });
            }
       });
   console.log("tabb: "+tab_etat_initial_joueur);    
  });
```

the result of ajax seems to be good:

but the multiple table aren't be modified. Nothing is written to this variable.
thanks for you help
Nicolas

Answer (score 0):

```
grille:,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,, essai_ajax.js:4:9
tabb: ,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,, essai_ajax.js:31:12
(8) […]
​
0: {…}
​​
id_date: "1"
​​
id_etat_joueur_initial: "2"
​​
id_joueur: "1"
​​
<prototype>: Object { … }
​
1: Object { id_date: "1", id_joueur: "1", id_etat_joueur_initial: "0" }
​
2: Object { id_date: "1", id_joueur: "2", id_etat_joueur_initial: "0" }
​
3: Object { id_date: "1", id_joueur: "2", id_etat_joueur_initial: "0" }
​
4: Object { id_date: "2", id_joueur: "1", id_etat_joueur_initial: "0" }
​
5: Object { id_date: "2", id_joueur: "1", id_etat_joueur_initial: "0" }
​
6: Object { id_date: "2", id_joueur: "2", id_etat_joueur_initial: "0" }
​
7: Object { id_date: "2", id_joueur: "2", id_etat_joueur_initial: "3" }
​
length: 8
​
<prototype>: Array []
essai_ajax.js:20:22

​
```